# Mapping dynamic sql pivot fields to an entity possible or write pivot query in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I execute a stored procedure which returns results from a dynamic pivot. Since its a dynamic pivot I am unable to estimate what the value of the result headers. My query is being returned fine, I am not sure as to the mapping of this header column(s) a property in my object which is then send to excel. Should I just try to write the query in LINQ?  I need to render my SQL result in the following format to excel:

In the following TSBNumber is a property, SYstemXY is a **VALUE** of property Called SystemFullName for which the value is diplayed in the header and the datetime? is a property called CLosedDate

Sample Data Returned from SQL:

```
**TSBNumber**   SystemXY   SystemBB   SystemTT
asdas          1/1/2013    
1231                      1/1/2014
12312          1/1/2013
ASAWS                     1/1/2013
awsdS                               1/1/2013
```

Executing the stored procedure

```
return db.Database.SqlQuery<ServiceTsbExportDataRow>("[dbo].[spExportServiceTSB] @parm1, @parm2, @parm3, @parm4, @parm5",
                    new SqlParameter("parm1", StartDate),
                    new SqlParameter("parm2", EndDate),
                    new SqlParameter("parm3", UserRoleID),
                    new SqlParameter("parm4", SelectedSystemIDs),
                    new SqlParameter("parm5", SelectedTsbIDs)
                    ).ToList().ToHTMLTable();
```

Entity mapping the properties **ServiceTsbExportDataRow**

```
public class ServiceTsbExportDataRow
    {
        //This property gets displayd fine since i know the mapping
        public string  TSBNumber { get; set; }

        //Now How do I display my SystemFullName property? string array?

    }
```

**TOHTML Table METHOD**

```
public static string ToHTMLTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
        {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection props =
                TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            builder.Append("<table border=\"1\">");

            builder.Append("<tr>");

            for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
            {
                builder.Append("<td>");

                PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];

                builder.Append(prop.Name);

                builder.Append("</td>");
            }
            builder.Append("</tr>");

            object[] values = new object[props.Count];
            foreach (T item in data)
            {
                builder.Append("<tr>");

                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    builder.Append("<td>");

                    builder.Append(props[i].GetValue(item));

                    builder.Append("</td>");
                }

                builder.Append("</tr>");

            }

            builder.Append("</table>");
            return "<html><body>" + builder.ToString() + "</body></html";
        }
```

**Finally Sending to excel**

```
ExcelHelpers.ExportToExcel(context.HttpContext, typeName, htmlTable);
```

Comment: Pivot + LINQ  = mess. Pivot + mapping = impossible.  Stick to how you do it now. You may want to use Dapper to run the sproc. It's easy and it's faster than anything.

Comment: So with Dapper I could easily map the dynamic columns being returned to my entity?

Comment: Well, you get a dynamic result. You'll have to modify your ToHTMLTable method to handle a dynamic. That's not hard, a dynamic is basically a dictionary of property names + values.

Comment: @GertArnold I am trying it with the Dapper, It has a SQLMapper function